# How can you tell if a database is down or unavailable?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jms

I am using a Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer to consume messages from a queue. The messages are then saved to an Oracle database.

When the database goes down, I throw an exception out of the onMessage method and that leaves the message on the queue to be reprocessed. Below you can see that on a DataAccessResourceFailureException and CannotCreateTransactionException exception, I throw the exception out of the method, which puts it back on the queue. The other exceptions do not save the message; they correspond to data problems and such.

```
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message mqMessage) {
    ...get the message blah, blah, blah
    try {
        this.theService.doMessage(tmaticMessage, theHandler);
    } catch (DataAccessResourceFailureException e) {
        this.slowDown(mqMessage);
        throw e;
    } catch (CannotCreateTransactionException e) {
        this.slowDown(mqMessage);
        throw e;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        ...
    } catch (TmUnusableMessageException e) {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Reading the Spring docs, I discovered that DataAccessResourceFailureException should be thrown "... when a resource fails completely: for example, if we can't connect to a database using JDBC." The problem is that I just did a test where I had the DBA take the database down and got a new exception: CannotCreateTransactionException. So that is one more exception that can be thrown. I am wondering if there are others.

I am using Spring Connections and getHibernateTemplate() to make my calls. Here is the question. How do I know what exceptions can be thrown when a database goes down?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the complexity is caused by various way you can 'take a database down'. For example:

- deleting a table
- deleting entire database
- disabling a db user account
- shutting down the database server

All can be considered as 'taking a database down', but each could cause a different exception being thrown

If you browse through following sections in spring javadoc, there are lists of exceptions that could be thrown:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/package-frame.html

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/package-frame.html